# Is it possible to use CefSharp in XBAP application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cefsharp, xbap

I have tried to use CefSharp in XBAP application, but can't seem to get it loading. Everything is fine if I use plain WinForms or WFP application, but in XBAP application it doesn't load the Cef related assemblies.

I'm not sure how I can include the necessary assebly files to the XBAP application for the OneClick deployment. I have used NuGET in Visual Studio to include CefSharp to the XBAP application, but only CefSharp.dll, CefSharp.Core.dll and CefSharp.WPF.dll (or WinForms) is included in the Application Files of the XBAP publish.

XBAP needs to be in AnyCPU mode. I think XBAP will load the 64bit asseblies and have tried to include those from CefSharp. I have also tried to copy all the other CefSharp related asseblies to the Application Files folder, but that does nothing. And I think they should be added by somehow else to the XBAP application deployment itself.

Anyhow... does anyone know should this be possible? E.g. create a XBAP browser application which uses CefSharp.WPF (or CefSharp.WinForms if I wrap WinForms application inside the WPF XBAP application). What I'm ultimately after is that XBAP has the chromium browser component in use.

Comment: Here's possibly related information to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcc9ce01-04bb-4c67-b635-4bebc702342c/warning-due-to-xbap-native-code-and-64-bit-?forum=netfx64bit It would be OK for me to have a limitation that my XBAP would only work in 64Bit environment, if I'd just get it working.

Comment: And more information: If I use 32bit CefSharp asseblies, I get an error:
 
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core, Version=53.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. And if I use 64bit assemblies, I get an error: 

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comment: There are no instructions, you'd have to work it out for yourself. You have to find a way to load the unmanaged resources. So do some research on xbap loading unmanaged resources, find out if it's even possible. You may find that CefGlue or ChromiumFx may be better suited. Good luck!